# Correct way of performing multiple sequential actions over a Python list

Tags: python

I have to perform multiple sequential operations over a Python list that stores lines of a text in order to clean that data. Currently (as you can see bellow) I am creating a new variable every time each operation is performed. My question is: is there a better (more pythonistic) way of doing all these actions without creating a new variable every time I want to change the data?

This is just an example of what I am currently doing:

```
corpus_1 = [strip_non_alphanum(line) for line in corpus]

corpus_2 = [line for line in corpus_1 if line.rstrip()]

corpus_3 = [strip_multiple_whitespaces(line) for line in corpus_2]

train_data_1 = [line.split(' ') for line in corpus_3]

train_data = [list(filter(None, line)) for line in train_data_1]
```

Comment: You could just have one variable `train_data` instead of `corpus_1`, `corpus_2`, etc, and perform all operations on that one.

Comment: You can just use a single variable. You've simply decided to use multiple ones. Also, you could wrap all your operations in a single function and use that function in one list comprehension. Unlikely to be a big deal, I don't see any huge issues with your code.

Comment: Just use a regular `for` loop? List comprehensions are convenience, not necessarily much faster, and there's no point iterating the entire list 5 times.

Comment: So could I do something like:

    train_data = [strip_non_alphanum(line) for line in corpus]

    train_data = [line for line in train_data if line.rstrip()]

Comment: you could create corpus_1 as you have done and then perform all following operations in corpus1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others already mentioned in the comments, you could do all these consecutive operations as following:

```
train_data = []
for line in corpus:
    line = strip_non_alphanum(line)
    if line.rstrip():
        elem = list(filter(None,strip_multiple_whitespaces(line).split()))
        train_data.append(elem)
```